# How to have a single TableVIew with Multiple Custom Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a table view that I want 3 different custom cells in it, right now this code only has one.

How can I modify my code so that case 2 and case 9 both have their own custom table cells with their own cell identifiers?  Keep in mind this code is inside an if/else statement because I have 2 different tableviews in my VC.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;

    if (tableView == self.mytableview)
    {
    }
    else if (tableView == self.vitalsTableView)
    {
            CellIdentifier = @"textCell";
            VitalsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Blood Pressure";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Respiratory Rate";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Smoking Status";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: do you want different UITableViewCell styleTypes or do u want to inherit from UITableViewCell and create your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like you already have but with a minor modification of the class you modify and the identifiers, I hope I got what you were asking.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;

if (tableView == self.mytableview)
{
}
else if (tableView == self.vitalsTableView)
{
    if ([indexPath row] == 2 || [indexPath row] == 9) {
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell2Or9";
        Cell2or9 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 2:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Blood Pressure";
                break;
            case 9:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Smoking Status";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        CellIdentifier = @"CellNot2Or9";
        CellNot2or9 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Respiratory Rate";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if i don't know the index path for row which have custom cell type 2? Can i use other conditions like instead of    if ([indexPath row] == 2 || [indexPath row] == 9) ?

Comment: here is more detail what i m trying to do:- if ([string1 isequalsToString @"silver"]){cellIdentifier = @"cell1"} else if ([string1 isequalsToString @"gold"]){cellIdentifier = @"cell2"}  instead of    if ([indexPath row] == 2 || [indexPath row] == 9) ?

Comment: You should be able to do this based on any condition you want. Indices usually make sense but I can see a lot of other use cases.

Comment: great i tried it and it works, i used static custom cells through storyboard and set the cell identifier for each custom cell and i can change or identify the cell based on any condition. will post my code in answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier;

     NSString *membershipType = [membershipTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if ([membershipType isEqualToString:@"silver"]||[membershipType isEqualToString:@"gold"])
     {
         cellIdentifier = @"cell";
     }
     else if ([membershipType isEqualToString:@"platinum"])
     {
         cellIdentifier = @"premiumCustomCell";
         cell.customCellImageView.image = [cellImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if (!cell) {
         cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.headingLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```